# Какой паттерн проектирования использовать для написания блога?

Tags: php, проектирование, шаблоны-проектирования

Представте пустую страницу сайта

И вот нужно на эту пустую страницу набросать элементов
-заголовок
-сообщения
-комментарии к сообщениям
-поиск
-ключевые слова

потом придет другой программер и решит дописать новый модуль
и т.д.

Так вот я писал и блоги и сайты
но потом возникали проблемы
допустим чтобы добавить меню сортировки текста приходилось перелопачивать весь код

Хочется при написании нового проекта все это учесть, т.е. разбить проект по модульно и сделать код не зависимым друг от друга. чтоб можно было дорабатывать

Что посоветуете?

Есть ли примеры шаблонов которые подойдут в этом случае

В дальнейшем я хочу предоставить проект для всеобщего пользования и очень хочется чтобы любой программист мог легко его дорабатывать под свои нужды

Comment: Как вы смотрите на Zend Framework? Это Вам подойдёт 100% процентов.

Answer (score 2):

Вы не с той стороны подходите к поставленной задаче.

**Суть проблемы**

Для реализации готового проекта (в вашем случае блога) вам придется реализовать далеко не один шаблон проектирования. В вашей работе наверняка встретится ряд проблем, которые можно решить используя тот или иной шаблон. Например:

- Организация точки входа в приложение ([Front Controller](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/front-controller.html), [Page Controller](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/page-controller.html)).
- Разбиение приложения на слои ([MVC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel), [MVP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter), ...)
- Инкапсуляция бизнес-логики ([Transaction Script](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/transaction-script.html), [Domain Model](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/domain-model.html)).
- Инкапсуляция слоя источника данных ([Active Record](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveRecord), [Data Mapper](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/data-mapper.html), [Table Gateway](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/table-data-gateway.html), ...)
- Решение проблемы с зависимостями одних подсистем от других ([Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), [Service Locator](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.org/ru/latest/More/ServiceLocator/README.html), [Dependency Injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), ...)
- Ряд проблем, связанных с несовместимостью сторонних компонентов ([Adapter](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), [Facade](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), [Bridge](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)).

Часть из перечисленных выше шаблонов так или иначе связана между собой. И все это, лишь малая часть из существующих на сегодняшний день шаблонов проектирования.

Думаю вы уже поняли, реализация **только** MVC не позволит вам получить полноценное приложение. Те, кто считают, что реализовав MVC вы получите готовый блог, по всей видимости плохо представляют что такое шаблоны проектирования, и когда они применяются.

**Что делать?**

Если у вас очень мало опыта в проектировании (именно *Проектировании*, а не в программировании) приложений, я бы рекомендовал вам начать работать с каким-либо существующим **фреймворком** (Symfony, Silex, Laravel, Zend, Yii, ...). В таких фреймворках, большинство проектных решений уже принято за вас. Кроме того, в документации по коду часто отражено, что какая-то из подсистем реализует тот или иной шаблон проектирования. Это поможет вам в изучении вопросов проектирования систем.

**Что почитать?**

Существует большое количество книг по шаблонам проектирования. Список ниже, это только отправная точка, но никак не исчерпывающее библиографическое исследование:

1. Э. Гамма, Р. Хелм, Р. Джонсон, Дж. Влиссидес, Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования.
2. М. Фаулер, Шаблоны корпоративных приложений.
3. М. Зандстра, PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования

Comment: Если у кого-то есть дополнения по списку литературы о шаблонах проектирования вообще или об их реализации в PHP, можете смело править ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей конечно же подходит [MVC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Controller), но зачем писать что то свое, если есть уже готовое: CodeIgniter, CakePHP, Yii, Zend Framework, Symfony и т.д.. В учебных целях можно попробовать написать свой велосипед, но всерьез на него рассчитывать не стоит

Comment: Дополню ответ: Если выбрать Yii, то там расписан процесс создания блога http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/ru/start.overview